# How to use a callback function in OnClick in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which I use when mapping each element of my array like so:

```
                  <DropDown
                    options={OPERATIONS}
                    placeholder={"Select operation"}
                    value={setOperation}
                    parentWidth={"47%"}
                    childWidth={"20%"}
                    makeSelection={this.selectOperation, ()=>this.checkIndex(index)} //I need the index as well
                  />
```

I would like to use `checkIndex` as a callback to `this.selectOperation`

In the DropDown component, this is how `makeSelection` is used:

```
    {options.map((option, index) => {
      return (
        <li key={index} onClick={() => { makeSelection(option); this.toggleDropDown(); }}>
          <p>{option.name}</p>
        </li>
      );
    })}
```

And this is how `selectOperation`  is defined in my component:

```
  selectOperation(op) {
    this.setState({
      setOperation: op
    })
  }
```

To summarize, I need to use the index to set a value in my array which is equal to the `setOperation`, so I need a callback to when the value has been set.

Also, I'm unable to do  `makeSelection={() => this.selectOperation}` since that causes a maximum update depth reached problem

Edit: I should mention that I'm not trying to change the structure of the DropDown menu since I have not written that component so I would prefer to not change it

Comment: What does the `checkIndex` look like?

Comment: pls try `makeSelection={this.selectOperation, index}`

Comment: How about `makeSelection={option => { this.selectOperation(option); this.checkIndex(index); }}` (as far as I can tell you don't really want/need a callback, all you want is to call two functions. So just use an anonymous function that does exactly that)

Comment: @NguyễnVănPhong `checkIndex` is just console logging the index currently

Comment: @ChrisG, I tried this method, but if I do `console.log(this.state. setOperation, "op")` in `checkIndex`, it shows up as undefined

Comment: @ChrisG, so it turns out that its undefined initially but after I select a second option from the dropdown, it updates to the first one I had selected. Which I think is because of the callback problem

Comment: You're logging state right after changing it. That will show the old value, because setting state is asynchronous. The code works fine.

Comment: Yes, but if it was working fine then I would be able to see the value I selected from the dropdown in my input as soon as I select it just like it was working before. Right now, I have to click on a second value for the input to be updated with the first value

Comment: You need to create a [mre] so we can fix the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect what you are looking for is how to pass a callback to the component that allows you to pass data back to the other component using your Dropdown.

Here's a really simple example with no state being updated. I used the fairly universal onChange prop name for the callback and when called it receives the index you mentioned and the `option` object. You can send whatever you want in that callback and document what it receives

```js
const DropDown = (props) => {
  const { options, onChange } = props;
  
  const handleClick = (item, i) => {
    return (e) => {
      if (typeof onChange === "function") {
        // you decide what to send back to other component
        onChange(item, i);
      }
    };
  };
  return (
     <ul> {options.map((option, index) =>  (
          <li key={index} onClick={handleClick(option, index)}>
            <strong>{option.name}</strong>
          </li> )
     )}</ul> );
};

const App = () => {
  const options = [{ name: "foo" }, { name: "bar" }];
  // arguments determined by whatever is passed to it when called in DropDown comp
  const handleChange = (opt, i) => {
    console.log(`Name:${opt.name}, Index: ${i}`);
  };
  return (<DropDown options={options} onChange={handleChange} />);
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
li{list-style:none; border:2px solid #ccc; width:100px; font-size:1.3em;padding:.5em; text-align:center}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<h3>Click item for result in console</h3>
<div id="react"></div>
```